# Timestamp not working with firebase-functions-test

Tags: javascript, firebase, testing, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

I'm using firebase-admin 8.6.0 and firebase-functions-test 0.1.6 which has support for Firestore Timestamps in testing (as of 0.1.5 https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions-test/releases) but am still receiving an error message when trying to use them with `test.firestore.makeDocumentSnapshot`.

Can someone help me understand the error in my implementation?

```
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
admin.initializeApp();
const db = admin.firestore();
const settings = { timestampsInSnapshots: true};
db.settings(settings);

const timestamp = admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp();
const testingTimestamp1 = admin.firestore.Timestamp.now();
const testingTimestamp2 = admin.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(new Date);

import * as TestFunctions from 'firebase-functions-test';

const firebaseConfig = {
    databaseURL: 'https://...HIDDEN...',
    projectId: '...HIDDEN...',
    storageBucket: '...HIDDEN...appspot.com',
}

const test = TestFunctions(firebaseConfig, 'service-account-dev.json');

const data({
  timestamp,
  testingTimestamp1,
  testingTimestamp2,
});

const snap = test.firestore.makeDocumentSnapshot(data, path);

const wrapped = test.wrap(processImport);
await wrapped(snap, {params: testParams});
```

I can't get any of the three timestamp options to work. The latter one I tried learning from @the0rem in https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions-test/pull/28 but to no avail. I always receive this error:

> Cannot encode [object Object]to a Firestore Value. Local testing does not yet support Firestore geo points.`

Comment: What is `test`?  Did you miss showing an import somewhere?

Comment: Sorry, @DougStevenson, I took some shortcuts in writing my question since I was synthesizing pieces from multiple files. I believe I have all the relevant pieces in the code example above now.

Comment: Just to make sure - the title of this question says @firebase/testing, which is for the web client SDK, but firebase-functions-test is for backend code running on Cloud Functions.  Could you edit the title if it's not consistent?

Comment: Also, if your question is really about firebase-functions-test, consider posting a bug report on the project GitHub.  https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions-test

Comment: Good pointers. I've changed the title, and I thought about posting a bug report, but seeing as how that had already been done and seemingly solved and closed, I figured it was just a problem with my not understanding how to implement correctly. Hence the post here.

Comment: Do you actually use geopoints anywhere, as the error message suggests?  If not, it sounds like, at the very least, a bug in the error message.

Comment: No I'm not using geopoints. I can write up a bug report tomorrow or Saturday on this note then.

Comment: any updates on this? firebase.firestore.Timestamp is not working for me with firebase emulators, I don't get any kind of error message though

Comment: No, I went another route with things but I would be curious if anyone finds a solution.

Answer (score 3):

I was excited when I saw your question because I just faced the same issue. Anyway, here is how I finally solved it. This is the JSON data that I saved from my Firestore database:

```
const customer = { 
    username: "A8tAz6wdtucMNKvWSgDkx4bquc2", 
    timestamp: { 
        _seconds: 1578762627, 
        _nanoseconds: 828000000 
    }, 
    role: "user" 
};
```

Note that `timestamp` is just a plain object with two properties: `_seconds` and `_nanoseconds`. This is where the error "Cannot encode [object Object]to a Firestore Value." comes from i.e. the data object, `customer`, contains another object, `timestamp`, which Firestore is unable to parse. What we do to solve this is to make sure that `timestamp` is not a plain object but an instance of `admin.firestore.Timestamp`. And here is how you do that:

```
const seconds = customer.timestamp._seconds;
const nanosecs = customer.timestamp._nanoseconds;

// create a new Timestamp object passing in the required constructor arguments
const properTimestamp = new admin.firestore.Timestamp(seconds, nanosecs);
customer.timestamp = properTimestamp; // update the timestamp reference in your data object
// Now you can do this
test.firestore.makeDocumentSnapshot(customer, '/users/A8tAz6wdtucMNKvWSgDkx4bquc2')
```

Now if you do `console.log(customer);` you will see that the timestamp object is an instance of `admin.firestore.Timestamp`, here is the console output:

```
// OUTPUT
{
    username: 'A8tAz6wdtucMNKvWSgDkx4bquc2',
    timestamp: Timestamp { _seconds: 1578762627, _nanoseconds: 828000000 },
    role: 'user'
}
```

PS: I got the answer by checking how Firebase was trying to parse the values/objects in the data. Here is where the parsing was failing and the exception was being thrown (in the file: `../node_modules/firebase-functions-test/lib/providers/firestore.js:165:15`):

```
if (val instanceof firebase_admin_1.firestore.Timestamp) {
        return {
            timestampValue: val.toDate().toISOString(),
        };
    }
```